# How to edit my query to present the output per day?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Instead of returning 5 rows, how can I edit the following query to return

```
date --- rows found
date --- rows found
date --- rows found
```

here is the query

```
SElECT * FROM emails WHERE maildate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY) and company_id = 1 order by maildate desc
```

Comment: What does your table look like? And what data **specifically** do you want to return? Do you just want to return the string `date --- rows found` three times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group on `maildate` and `COUNT(*)` should work:

```
SELECT maildate, COUNT(*) as TotalEmails --change alias as desired
FROM emails
WHERE maildate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY) 
AND company_id = 1 
GROUP BY date(maildate) --Remove timestamp for grouping
ORDER BY maildate desc
```

Although it's unclear what you want returned.  Sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: Hi, I made this change in order to work `GROUP BY date(maildate)`. Thank you

Comment: @Pashiamas Right on, I didn't know the column type.  Edited that in for clarity.

Comment: `SELECT DATE(maildate)`